# Set form submission action depending on 2 select values

Tags: jquery, html

I have 1 form and 2 select inside. I need to change form submission action url which is depends on onchange of values of 2 select inputes.Form should be submited onclick of button. Here is my code and i can get values of changed select inputs, but stucked how to make it work as i want and make it short code + right

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var select1_val = $("#select1").val();
    var select2_val = $("#select2").val();

    alert(select1_val + select2_val);

    if (select1_val == '1-1' && select2_val == '2-1') {
      var url = 'example.html';
    } else if (select1_val == '1-2' && select2_val == '2-2') {
      var url = 'example2.html';
    }
    $('#myform').attr('action', url);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1-1">Something 1</option>
    <option value="1-2">Something 2</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select2">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="2-1">Something 1</option>
    <option value="2-2">Something 2</option>
  </select>

  <button id='submitBTN'>Search</button>
  <form>
```

Comment: It's a much better idea to submit to the same place every time and then change the logic performed on the server based on the parameters passed.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for reply. I have edited js code, but still not working, but i think i cuz of i gave wrong `attr`. I think it is better get select values on form submit and with `if` `else if` conditions set url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my code. Best way is get values of select inputes and in Jquery code write conditions `if` and `else if`, after get URL depends on condition and write it to `attr` by jquery. Here is working code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(function(event) {

    var select1_val = $("#select1").val();
    var select2_val = $("#select2").val();

    if (select1_val === "" || select2_val === "") {
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      //alert(select1_val + select2_val);

      if (select1_val == '1-1' && select2_val == '2-1') {
        var url = 'example.html';
      } else if (select1_val == '1-2' && select2_val == '2-2') {
        var url = 'example2.html';
      }

      //alert(url);
      $('#myform').attr('action', '/' + url);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1-1">Something 1</option>
    <option value="1-2">Something 2</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select2">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="2-1">Something 1</option>
    <option value="2-2">Something 2</option>
  </select>

  <button id='submitBTN'>Search</button>
  <form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about validation you want but I am just trying to develop basic based on 2 validations.

1. If any of them are empty, do nothing.
2. If both of them are not empty then do validation check and change url accordingly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select1').on('change', function(){urlValidation()});
  $('#select2').on('change', function(){urlValidation()});
});

function urlValidation() {
  var val1 = $('#select1').val();
  var val2 = $('#select2').val();
  
  if (val1 === "" || val2 === "") {
    // Do nothing
     alert ("Doing Nothing!");
  } else if (val1 != "" && val2 != "") {
    if (val1 === "1-1") {
      // Next step validation to check select2 value and apply URL
      if (val2 === "2-1") {
        $('#myForm').attr('action', '1-1-2-1.html');
      } if (val2 === "2-2") {
        $('#myForm').attr('action', '1-1-2-2.html');
      }
    } else if (val1 === "1-2") {
      // Next step validation to check select2 value and apply URL
      if (val2 === "2-1") {
        $('#myForm').attr('action', '1-2-2-1.html');
      } if (val2 === "2-2") {
        $('#myForm').attr('action', '1-2-2-2.html');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="depend_on_selections.html" id="myForm">
  <select id="select1">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1-1">Something 1</option>
    <option value="1-2">Something 2</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select2">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="2-1">Something 1</option>
    <option value="2-2">Something 2</option>
  </select>

  <button id='submitBTN'>Search</button>
<form>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I like your validation for empty select values
 `if (val1 === "" || val2 === "") {
    // Do nothing
     alert ("Doing Nothing!");
  } ` and i will use it in my code, but in different way.